# Uniformly adjust height and width of parent wrapper according to the inner children

Tags: css

I have an Ads campaign web page where I will publish videos or images. I load the content using script. If the fetched content is an **image** it will be display as shown below.

[image]

The image will properly wrap inside the white wrapper.

**But**, when a **video** is loaded into the same wrapper it will display as below

[image]

Ad contents will be random, it can be any image or video. All types of images with different orientation will fit properly but the video won't.

Videos, will always be in the same width and height.

**HTML**

*When video is loaded*

```
<div class="campaign-wrap">
    <div id="ad_area" style="text-align:center;">
        <video src="https://video.serve.in/files/video_messi.mp4" onplay="window.V.ads.push({id:380, loaded: true, server:'video.serve.in'})" preload="auto" autoplay="" playsinline="" muted="" controls="" type="video/mp4" id="vid" width="300" height="250"></video>
    </div>
</div>
```

*When image is loaded*

```
<div class="campaign-wrap">
    <div id="ad_area" style="text-align:center;">
        <img src="https://video.serve.in/getad.img?libID=383&amp;placement=ad_area" alt="hello" title="hello" border="0" width="300" height="600">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

The style I have added to the parent wrapper is

```
.campaign-wrap {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    padding: 10px;
}
```

The content inside `div` #ad_area is loaded using script.

How can I uniformly place the Ad inside the wrapper with equal padding all around **Or** how to adjust the wrapper with respect to the inner content ?

Any advice please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Right now i can't test it with your code but see if any of suggested method in the article works for you.
 https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try this:

```
.campaign-wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* ... */
}
```

Explanation: flexbox is a powerful feature of modern css that solves some formatting issues that have given a lot of problems in the past: one of them is vertical alignment. [Compatibility table](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).